# Index of "for" inside "setInterval"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have an object and i put it in a Array, and the i iterate the array with `for` and for each object in the array i put a set interval for calling a method of the object with a parameter, but i cant.
This is my "Class".

```
    function ClassTest() {
        this.test = function(word) {
            console.log(word);
        }
    }
```

The i create the object and put it on a Array:

```
    var array = [];
    var objectTest = new ClassTest();


    array.push(objectTest);
```

And when i set the Intervals:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].loop = setInterval(function() {
            array[i].test("hello")
        }, 1000);
    }
```

The problem is that the var `i` in the setInterval function dosent exist, i can create a var `index` and the it exist but i dont understand why `index` exist and the var `i` not.:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var index = i;
        array[i].loop = setInterval(function() {
            array[index].test("hello")
        }, 1000);
    }
```

I get this error when i dont use the `index` var:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

Comment: By the time you execute the callback of `setInterval`, `i` equals `array.length`. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) how to solve this.

Comment: Could you share what's the error coming in first place. Or just "i" doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `for` loop executes immediately. By the time your `setInterval()` executes for the first time, your `for` loop will have long since finished and your `i` will be outside of the range of your array.

#### Example

In this example, our `array` has a `length` of 3. When our `for` loop finishes, our `i` variable will be equal to `3`. The number `3` will be displayed three times in our JavaScript console if we log `i` within the `setTimeout`:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is incorrect in both cases, with or without `index`. There is only *one* `i` variable in your code, and by the time the timeouts fire, it will have the value `array.length`.

This is a problem known as "closing over the loop variable", and one clean way to solve it is:

```
array.forEach(function (item) {
    item.loop = setInterval(function () {
        item.test("hello");
    }, 1000);
});
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) has several answers that explain in depth the reasons for the behavior you are seeing, but most of the highly-voted answers are excessively convoluted when you're working with an array. `forEach` is the way to go.

Comment: If you need to support IE 8, however, then `Array.prototype.forEach()` is unavailable.

Comment: @Phylogenesis If you need to support IE 8, you can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).